# Alterar texto JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Quero alterar o texto da tag text com JavaScript.

```
<text id =txtrect x="5" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11" fill="white" >
  Rect
</text>
```

Tentei isto mas não altera

```
document.getElementById(txtrect).innerHTML=teste;
```

Comment: Tente substituir `ìd =txtrect` por `id="txtrect"` e `document.getElementById(txtrect).innerHTML=teste;` por `document.getElementById("txtrect").innerHTML = "teste";` E estude sobre a sintaxe do javascript. Em programação, cada vírgula pode alterar o resultado. Essas aspas faltando denotam que você está começando. Então de agora em diante, preste mais atenção quando estiver digitando código. Sem mencionar que os atributos `x` e `y` não devem existir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mude para:

```
<text id="txtrect" x="5" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11" fill="white" >
  Rect
</text>
```

e

```
document.getElementById("txtrect").innerHTML="teste";
```

Isso deve resolver seu problema.

**Update**

Aconselho que você dê uma olhada nesse tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp
Vai resolver os seus problemas com javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Basta fazer assim:

```js
document.querySelector("#txtrect").innerHTML ="Teste";
```

```html
<text id =txtrect x="5" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11" fill="white" >
  Rect
</text>
```